Why go-staticcheck reports "unused method" when implementing interface
I have written a fairly simple code. It simply "implements" the factory interface in a stateless way. It works as expected, however I got a warning from Golang linter that both make() and update() methods are unused, which is clearly not true.
Have I written non-idiomatic Golang code, or is linter just too stupid to understand it? In most other languages this wouldn't be a problem, but Golang doesn't allow you to ignore linter warnings.
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

type Factory[T any] interface {
    make() *T
    update(*T, string, string)
}

type FooFactory struct {
}

func (f *FooFactory) make() *Foo {
    return &Foo{}
}

func (f *FooFactory) update(foo *Foo, key string, val string) {
    switch key {
    case "name":
        foo.name = val
    }
}

type Service[T any] struct {
    factory Factory[T]
}

func (s *Service[T]) Run() {
    foo := s.factory.make()
    s.factory.update(foo, "name", "qwerty")
    fmt.Printf("%v", foo)
}

// prints qwerty
func main() {
    service := &Service[Foo]{
        factory: &FooFactory{},
    }
    service.Run()
}



Have you saved the file with the above func main in your example? If staticcheck doesn't detect Run being called anywhere, and if this is part of the main package that isn't exported, then it's valid that the functions aren't reachable.

The linter is not part of the go toolchain, you are free to ignore it all you want, or disable warnings with various directives

Looks to be the same bug as https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/issues/1440.

It was a different bug. It's fixed in https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/commit/663bb6d3533dc62cc0b49176a889fe4efddae191

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
